# How can I upload adk into the Bitbucket Downloads using Bitbucket Pipeline?

Tags: android, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am developing an android app and it is managed on the Bitbucket. I tried to use the "Pipeline" feature of the Bitbucket.

I found some references for it.

My first step is very simple. I just want to build "APK" file and upload it into the Bitbucket Downloads

[image]

I generated the config file like below:

```
image: mingc/android-build-box:latest
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
          - curl -X POST --user ${BB_AUTH_STRING} "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk"
```

When I run this Pipeline, Build is successful. But the APK file is not uploaded into the "Downloads" of Bitbucket.

The error log is very simple:

```
+ curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk"
Warning: setting file ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk  failed!
```

What's wrong?
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.

Below config worked!

```sh
image: mingc/android-build-box:latest
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle

        script:
          # Build apk
          - chmod a+x ./gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug

        artifacts:
          - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk

    - step:
        script:
          # Saving artifact
          - curl -X POST --user ${BB_AUTH_STRING} "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
```

Comment: What should i pass in BB_AUTH_STRING ?

Comment: i am getting error + curl -X POST --user ${BB_AUTH_STRING} "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information